# create mysql table with json column inside spring boot , hibernate schema validation fails

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-data

I want to create a table with **Json** column .

I got an **entity** that represent that table, where the field that represents the json type uses a json converter:

The entity :

```
    @Entity
public class GroupEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String groupId;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String propertiesStr;


    public GroupEntity() {
        // For JPA
    }

    @Convert(converter = GroupPropertiesJsonConverter.class)
    private HostProperties propertiesDto;

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getPropertiesStr() {
        return propertiesStr;
    }

    public void setPropertiesStr(String propertiesStr) {
        this.propertiesStr = propertiesStr;
    }

    public HostProperties getPropertiesDto() {
        return propertiesDto;
    }

    public void setPropertiesDto(HostProperties propertiesDto) {
        this.propertiesDto = propertiesDto;
    }
}
```

and **GroupPropertiesJsonConverter** is :

```
public class GroupPropertiesJsonConverter implements
    AttributeConverter<HostProperties, String> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GroupPropertiesJsonConverter.class);
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(HostProperties hostProperties) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(hostProperties);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("coudln't convert HostProperties Dto to json, wont persist");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public HostProperties convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, HostProperties.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("couldn't convert json of properties to Dto", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the **sql script** :

```
create table group_entity (
    properties_str varchar(255) not null, 
    group_id varchar(255) not null, 
    properties_dto JSON, primary key (properties_str)
);
```

When the spring boot application I get the following **hibernate schema validation error**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [properties_dto] in table [group_entity]; found [json (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:92)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
```

So from what I understand, **Hibernate** resolve my **entity** field as `varchar`, even though I'm using the converter annotation .

Changing `properties_dto JSON` to `properties_dto varchar(255)` does solve it , but thats not json type!

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly configure this table?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to create one column of json type in entity class then simply go with

```
@Column(columnDefinition="json")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you convert it simply to a `String` it is simply a `String` property as far as Hibernate is concerned. Hibernate does not seem to support JSON out of the box so you have to implement your own user type to do so.

Here is an [article describing how to create a JSON user type](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/).